# jQUERY: Count elements which have do not have a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the number of span tags which have class `assigned-names` but do not have a class named `hidden`. Following is the HTML code:

```
<div class="assigned-values">
    <span class="assigned-names">
          <span class="name">Test 1</span>
    </span>
    <span class="assigned-names hidden">
          <span class="name">Test 2</span>
    </span>
    <span class="assigned-names hidden">
          <span class="name">Test 3</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

So, for the above HTML, The number of span tags which have class `assigned-names` but do not have class `hidden` is *1*.

I have tried following code, but it gives me length as 2:

`$('.assigned-values').find('span.assigned-names:not(:has(.hidden))').length`

Comment: Is it `assigned-names` or `assigned-name` ?, in your jquery code its `assigned-name` while in your HTML its `assigned-names`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply filter out the non-required elements using `not()` function:

```js
const elems = $(".assigned-values > .assigned-names").not(".hidden");
console.log(elems.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="assigned-values">
  <span class="assigned-names">
          <span class="name">Test 1</span>
  </span>
  <span class="assigned-names hidden">
          <span class="name">Test 2</span>
  </span>
  <span class="assigned-names hidden">
          <span class="name">Test 3</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.not('span.hidden')`. [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method remove elements from the set of matched elements.

```js
console.log($('.assigned-values').find('span.assigned-names').not('span.hidden').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="assigned-values">
    <span class="assigned-names">
          <span class="name">Test 1</span>
    </span>
    <span class="assigned-names hidden">
          <span class="name">Test 2</span>
    </span>
    <span class="assigned-names hidden">
          <span class="name">Test 3</span>
    </span>
    <span class="assigned-names">
          <span class="name">Test 1</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JQuery code has missed an 's' in 'span.assigned-name'

I have tried the following code and it works

```
var element = $('.assigned-values').find('span.assigned-names').not('.hidden').length
console.log(element.length);
```

The code outputs the value as 1